# Communicating with parent component

Tags: java, tapestry

I have the `MyPage.tml` page and `MyComponent.tml` component.

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <body>
        <t:mycomponent />
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to display some data  on `MyPage` based on what has happened in `MyComponent`. How can I make some data from `MyComponent` available to `MyPage`? Is there something like "reverse" parameters (child passing parameter to parent)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your component is available to you within your page as a variable where you can access the variables required from within your page like so:

```
@Component(id = "myComponent")
private MyComponent myComponent;

@SetupRender //or any other render event method
private void setup() {
    Object compVariable = myComponent.getYourVariable();
}
```

More elegant if you ask me is to use event bubbling as it makes it easer to refactor some logic out to a deeper component if needed.

Component:

```
@Inject
private ComponentResources resources;

@SetupRender //or any other lifecycle event method
private void triggerEvent() {
    Object yourVariable = new Object();
    resources.triggerEvent("YOUR_EVENT_NAME", new Object[]{yourVariable}, null);
    //add an event callback if needed where I use null here
}
```

Page:

```
@OnEvent(value = "YOUR_EVENT_NAME")
private void handleComponentEvent(Object yourVariable) {
    //do something with yourVariable
    //even return something which would then can be handled by your component callback handler
}
```

Comment: Maybe not my use can right now, but that's a nice one! Didn't know that was possible :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use usual tapestry parameter.

```
<t:mycomponent value="myValue"/>
```

If this value will be changed on the component side, it will be available on the container side and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I've used all three of these approaches, depending on context. I generally prefer event bubbling, where that makes sense.